# Add textile into rails-i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, internationalization, textile

I need to add some sort of markup in my localization files of my rails project. I want something like this:

```
en:
 hello: **Hello** world!

it:
 hello: ciao **mondo**!
```

and for example `**word**` could be converted with `<strong>word</strong>`. For example I'd like to add the textile support.
I've found r18n plugin that's is very nice, but it's way too different from the i18n-rails framework and has several features I don't actually need.

Do you know any plugin that could help me? I've not found anything so far. Do you have any suggestion about tutorial I can use to extend i18n and add this feature by my self. Is anyone interested in such functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that

```
RedCloth.new(t(:hello)).to_html
```

doesn't work?

Comment: I'm stupid actually should work! Any suggestion about how to automize it instead of call it every time?

Comment: I'd just put it in a helper method and use it only when you need markup formatted text.